# Creating a list of nearby locations within a rectangular region around the selected location

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of locations around a selected point within a rectangular boundary. The dimensions of the boundary are provided by *d1* and *d2*, where *d1* extends the rectangle in the East-West direction and *d2* extends the region in the North-South direction.
For example, if the latitude and longitude of a location point L83 are given as (x,y), the search space will create a rectangle region where the coordinate of the North-East (NE), North-West (NW), South-West (SW), and SouthEast (SE) corners will be

```
NE = (x+d1, y+d2)  
NW = (x-d1, y+d2)  
SW = (x-d1, y-d2)  
SE = (x+d1, y-d2)
```

Below is a snippet of the CSV data file:

```
LocId,Latitude,Longitude,Category
L1,4.5692,2.747,P
L2,2.2551,16.7944,H
L3,15.761,15.1464,R
L4,15.6516,5.1249,C
L5,6.0939,9.8601,S
L18,17.2331,18.7218,R
L47,16.3438,18.5479,H
L53,16.7774,17.4848,R
L83,16.9767,17.0477,R
L91,16.4508,18.9552,P
```

I have tried

```
 querylocid = "L83"
    d1=1.5
    d2=2.2
    
    infile = open(<CSV FILE NAME>, "r")
    infile.readline()
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip().split(",")
        if line[0] == querylocid:
            ne = (float(line[1])+d1, float(line[2])+d2)
            nw = (float(line[1])-d1, float(line[2])+d2)
            sw = (float(line[1])-d1, float(line[2])-d2)
            se = (float(line[1])+d1, float(line[2])-d2)
            
            # checking if location is within rectangle boundary
            if float(line[1]) >= nw[0] and float(line[1]) <= ne[0] and float(line[2]) >= sw[1] and float(line[2]) <= nw[1]:
                list.append(line[0])
                print(list)
```

which only gives me

```
['L83']
```

The output I am looking for is

```
['L3', 'L18', 'L47', 'L53', 'L91']
```

I can probably guess that the problem is *if line[0] == querylocid:*, but I'm unsure as to how to specify the rectangle boundaries around the selected location if I don't have this line.

Comment: `'L83'` does not even seem to be in your sample data. Anyway, if your indentation is correct, you only compare the coordinates if the ID is the same, so of course it can only match `L83`. And if the indentation is not correct, it will only match entries _after_ you find `L83` as before the ne, nw etc. are not set. You should iterate the file twice: first to find ne, nw, etc. and then to find the matches.

Answer (score 2):

To find all locations with an overlapping rectangle you can compute the difference of them and check if it smaller than twice the distance [along the same direction (longitudinal/latitudinal)], i.e. `abs(long1 -long2) < 2*d2`.

I used `itertools.combinations` to find all possible pairings.

Warning: the `string` to `float`casting is based a cheap check: `'.' in string`

```
import itertools as it

geo = """L1,4.5692,2.747,P
L2,2.2551,16.7944,H
L3,15.761,15.1464,R
L4,15.6516,5.1249,C
L5,6.0939,9.8601,S
L18,17.2331,18.7218,R
L47,16.3438,18.5479,H
L53,16.7774,17.4848,R
L91,16.4508,18.9552,P"""


# data from string to dictionary + casting numbers to float!
geo_data = {}
attrs = ['LocId', 'Latitude', 'Longitude' ,'Category']
for line  in geo.split('\n'):
    attrs_values = [float(g) if '.' in g else g for g in line.split(',')]
    
    geo_data[attrs_values[0]] = dict(zip(attrs[1:], attrs_values[1:]))


def is_in_interval(c1, c2, r):
    """c1, c2 are center of an interval with radius r, to have an intersection the maximum distance allowed is 2r"""
    return  abs(c2-c1) <= 2*r


# size of a single box
d1 = 1.5
d2 = 2.2

pairwise_overlapping_locations = []
for id1, id2 in it.combinations(geo_data, 2):
    lat1 = geo_data[id1]['Latitude']
    lat2 = geo_data[id2]['Latitude']
    is_in_lat = is_in_interval(lat1, lat2, d1)

    long1 = geo_data[id1]['Longitude']
    long2 = geo_data[id2]['Longitude']
    is_in_long = is_in_interval(long2, long1, d2)

    if is_in_lat and is_in_long:
        pairwise_overlapping_locations += [(id1, id2)]


print(pairwise_overlapping_locations)
print(set(it.chain(*pairwise_overlapping_locations)))
```

Output

```
[('L3', 'L18'), ('L3', 'L47'), ('L3', 'L53'), ('L3', 'L91'), ('L18', 'L47'), ('L18', 'L53'), ('L18', 'L91'), ('L47', 'L53'), ('L47', 'L91'), ('L53', 'L91')]
{'L91', 'L18', 'L47', 'L53', 'L3'}
```

Comment: Nice, but why do you combine the output to one set? This way you get all the locations that are somehow close to any other location, but not those close to a specific location.

Comment: @tobias_k just because I am not quite sure on how should look like the output... it depends on the needs. I formatted that way just to loop back to the question... I used `chain` to flat the pairs that are overlapping then `set` to remove repetitions, again just to loop back to the question.  `combs` contains the pair of overlapping id keys that together with `geo_data` can be used to access to the full information of the measurements